# Error Duplicate class androidx.databinding.xxxx Android Studio - Volley

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

Cuando ejecuto Build APK, para generar mi aplicativo, estaba funcionando bien, sin ningun problema, en mi MainActivity estaba editando una funcion y cuando lo finalice, se generó ese error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso fue, entonces vi en internet sobre esto y me dicen que revise mi build.gradle y el gradle-wrapper.properties pero tampoco veo algun error.

Adjunto mi build.gradle

```js
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prd.cocaapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:compilerCommon:3.2.0-alpha11'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'
}
```

Adjunto mi gradle-wrapper.properties

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar, ya recién estoy empezando en android studio

Comment: Estás implementando `material` dos veces en el gradle, puede que sea por eso el error. Considera poner tu `gradle` como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Parece que no, acabo de quitar el mas actualizado y no, me sigue saliendo lo mismo :/

Comment: Me refiero a esto: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'` y a esto: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'` es la misma librería, con dos versiones y por regla general, quita siempre la más vieja, no la más nueva.

Comment: Si, hice eso pero seguía saliendo lo mismo, lo que hice fue tantear cada uno y cuando comenté * implementation 'androidx.databinding:compilerCommon:3.2.0-alpha11' * se arregló, estoy buscando que podría hacer eso. Gracias igualmente por ayudarme

Comment: `databinding` no está repetida en ese `gradle`, pero puede que estés trabajando con módulos o algo así y que lo estés implementando desde otra parte.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía el mismo error, simplemente he comentado la línea de:

```
implementation 'androidx.databinding:compilerCommon:3.2.0-alpha11'
```